# Python centralized information

Tags: python, server, kivy, pymodbus

I am currently doing a development in Pyhton (Kivy) for some machines that will be installed in various parts of the city, I wish that all the information of the machines is centralized and updated in real time.

Example:

User X registers on machine 1, at 5 minutes he moves to machine 2 and can enter with the information he supplies on machine 1.

What method do you recommend to carry out this development?

Comment: Please post your question in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I already translated the post